# Karate Version 0.9.0.RC5 is not not running project developed in version 0.8.0.1

Tags: gherkin, karate

Getting Error: 
13:59:17.372 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('CLASSPATH:CreateUsers.feature');
13:59:17.372 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] ERROR com.intuit.karate.FileUtils - feature relative path resolution failed: Illegal char <:> at index 9: CL

I tried replacing ":" by "=" but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried it as `classpath:`, It is case sensitive.

```
callonce read('classpath:CreateUsers.feature')
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried "classpath" as well. Strangely it works as it is in 8.0.0.1 version
Anf if i change it to "classpath" in v8.0.0.1 then i get below error:
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateFileNotFoundException: could not find or read file: users.feature, prefix: CLASSPATH

Comment: ok, In documentation it is mentioned as `classpath:` only not as `CLASSPATH:`. https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files. so it will work fine if we stick with that ;)

Comment: if your file is outside src/test/java, try `file:` prefix with absolute path to the file.

Comment: My file is inside src/test/java, and yes in documentation it is classpath but it is not working out in my case, whereas as i mentioned same works in version v8.0.0.1

Comment: ok. i am not abke to replcate your issue. can you refer https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue and submit an issue